# Elastic search curl -X GET "localhost:9200/" Connection Refused

Tags: server, curl, elasticsearch

I have followed the instructions at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html to install elasticsearch on a clean install of Ubuntu Server 16.04.

I have run the following commands through terminal to install.

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.3.0.deb

sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-6.3.0.deb

sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload

sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service

sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

However when I run `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/"` I get the following error

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

This is the contents of `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: localhost
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
#
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes:
#
```

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated to help me get elasticsearch up and running.

Also worth pointing out that I am running on a 32 bit system

Comment: Did you modify the `network.host`? The documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html) suggests it should read `_local_`

Comment: @steeldriver yes I did. The initial value was `127.0.0.1` which didn't work and after a quick google I read somewhere to try `localhost` i will try `_local_` now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`network.host: 127.0.0.1` did the thing in my case**.

I had the same exact issue with ES 6.7.1. But neither `0.0.0.0` nor `localhost` worked for me as `network.host` values.

I ran the following command:

```
netstat -natp
```

I noticed I had this line in the list:

```
127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN
```

So I just put the listed host and it worked.